# What can I do to prevent a recurrence Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a code block like this.

```
$goto = Something....

if (!$goto) {

    $data = Logs::create([
        'event_id' => $settings['id'],
        'p_id'     => $settings['p_id'],
        'a_id'     => $settings['a_id'],
        'name'     => $accountname[1],
        'sku'      => $product['sku'],
        'status'   => 'warning',
        'voice'    => 'Poor internet connection!',
    ]);

    if ($data) {
        $new = Logs::where('id', $data->id)->first();
        $count = $settings->count;
        $left = $settings->limit - $count;
        $percent = round($settings->limit * $count / 100);
        event(new StatusLiked(
            $new['event_id'],
            $new['p_id'],
            $new['a_id'],
            $new['name'],
            $new['sku'],
            $new['status'],
            $new['created_at'],
            $count,
            $left,
            $percent,
            $new['voice']
        ));
    }
}
```

This code is repeated many times in the controller. This creates confusion and a long code. How can I prevent this?

Comment: by making a function

Comment: You can create an observer on your Logs model that will update the settings table. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#observers

Comment: status and voice value change according to the situation. how can i make it dynamic?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you creating the `Log` and then fetching it from the database (rather than use the instance you've just created)? Also, would you want the `StatusLiked` event to be fired after every new `Log` that is created or will it only be when specific Logs are created?

Comment: If get repeated in one controller use common function else use service for that.